# What part of a Buffer does glBufferData use

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, nio

What part of a `Buffer` does [`android.opengl.GLES20.glBufferData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20#glBufferData(int,%20int,%20java.nio.Buffer,%20int)) use?

The *convention* is that a NIO buffer consumer reads [`remaining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#remaining()) data items between [`position`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#position()) and [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit()). A quick experiment with a toy app and an emulated Android suggests that `position` at least is indeed taken into account. But on the other hand, the C-influenced OpenGL API has a somewhat low-level feel to it, and the function does come with its own `size` argument even though `remaining` already has that information in the typical NIO convention. So I wonder how far I can trust the rest of that convention.

**Is there some documentation which explicitly states that the used data starts at `position` and not the start of the buffer?** And ideally also clarifies the relationship between the `size` argument to `glBufferData` and the `Buffer.remaining()` value, particularly if the latter is less?

Barring such clear documentation, how far can I trust my experiments? Usually I tend to assume anything not documented might depend on implementation. Is there a *real* danger that some vendor graphics driver or future Android update might change the behavior at this Java API level and interpret buffers differently?

Should I be using [`Buffer.slice`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#slice()) just to be safe in terms of compatibility?